# base64 decode and write image / python3 / must be str, not bytes

Tags: python-3.x, image, base64

I've looked through about 10 different methods to do this, but no matter what I've tried the result seems to be the same.  I have a simple mdb that that I'm pulling a key/value pair where the value is b64 encoded images:

```
for key, value in db_cursor:
        with open(output_path, 'w') as of:
        of.write(base64.decodestring(value))
#       of.write(value.decode('base64'))
    break
```

Both methods result in:

```
write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `of.write(base64.decodestring(value).decode('utf-8'))`? (or any other protocol besides `utf-8`, honestly - for base64, `ascii` would work just as well). The `bytes.decode()` function decodes a bytes object into an actual string, given an assumed encoding (because it doesn't know what encoding the string-as-bytes would be using, in advance).

Comment: I have.  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 8: invalid start byte

Comment: And what gets printed when you do `print(base64.decodestring(value))`?